# Best way to address this Magento issue

Tags: magento

I am in need of some advice/pointers on how best to attack a problem I am faced with in Magento 1.4.0.1.

Here is the scenario:
Consider a product catalog of multiple thousands of products in which there are many and various retail markup percentages.
There is a need to sell some of those products to other retailers, and I need a way to easily categorise them into percentrage markup groups, so that the other traders can easily purchase items from us without needing to call and confirm pricing.

All products prices are added to the magento database including VAT - so the actual retail value is the starting point.

I think this needs to be done by adding an attribute on the products that determines the maximum discount level that can be applied to any given product.

Obviously, this would entail a massive amount of work to update every product.

Is there a way to achieve what we need that I don't yet know about (within Magento)?

Can single attribute values be mass-populated somehow, without affecting other attributes such as name/description/etc?

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Magento 1.4.1.1 but I don't believe that the differences should be meaningful:
*An example of how to achieve the wanted behavior will be as follows*: 
1. **main-menu->promotions->catalog->price rules** and create a new rule, let's call it: "30% off". 

[image]


2. Under **rule information** you can choose **customer groups** that will be included. 
3. go to (still under "Catalog Price Rule"): **actions** on the left bar and configure the **discount type** to be "by percentage" and the **Discount Amount** to 30.0


[image]


4. now all you have to do is group the customers into groups (according to discount) - this is something that you'll have to do once (go over all your customers) but then the maintenance will be easy. 

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in my scenario. That same customer might have 25% off a different set of products, and 15% off yet other products. I guess what I need is some way of assigning a discount value to the product instead of the customer group?
Perhaps a product group with a discount level applied to it, that can be applied to all products that can have that discount level?